# Kryonet disconnect() connection cannot get TCP address

Tags: sockets, tcp, kryonet

In my disconnect() method in the Listener, the InetSocketAddress object is always null. Why does this happen?

```
@Override
public void disconnected(Connection connection) {
    Log.info("Server disconnected from " + connection.getRemoteAddressTCP());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it's already disconnected. So there is no remote address.

Comment: @Fox32 A post that starts with the word 'because' cannot logically be said to not provide an answer. And I am certainly not requesting clarification or critiquing the question. Your comment makes no sense.

Comment: Is there any way to figure out which client disconnected? If there is no way to figure out who disconnected, that callback is basically useless. I need to be able to stop the processes the client invoked on the server after he/she logs out.

Comment: You would need to keep a map of `Connection` to client.